# Filtering a DataFrame index by another index or a value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a multi-indexed dataframe that looks like this:

```
                             status      value
id            country                             
1234            US          Complete      54            
2345            US          Ongoing       3 
                UK          Complete      343
                JP          Complete      54
                IT          Complete      32
3456            CA          Ongoing       20
                UK          Complete      123
                FR          Complete      245
```

I'm not sure how to make it so that I can filter the ID column by either the presence of a field in the other index (country) or one of the values.

Essentially it would be great if say I wanted all columns for all indexes that don't contain "US" and could get something back like this:

```
                             status      value
id            country                             
3456            CA          Ongoing       20
                UK          Complete      123
                FR          Complete      245
```

Or additionally be able to say "Filter out each ID in which at least 1 Status is Ongoing" and get this back:

```
                             status      value
id            country                             
1234            US          Complete      54
```

Eventually I'd like to be able to combine this but learning how to do each individually is probably a good first step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You 2nd question No `Ongoing`

```
sliceidx=~df.index.get_level_values(0).isin(df.loc[df.status=='Ongoing'].index.get_level_values(0))
df[sliceidx]
Out[474]: 
                status  value
id   country                 
1234 US       Complete     54
```

Your 1st question no `US`

```
sliceidx=df.index.get_level_values(0)[df.index.get_level_values(1)=='US']
df[~df.index.get_level_values(0).isin(sliceidx)]
Out[478]: 
                status  value
id   country                 
3456 CA        Ongoing     20
     UK       Complete    123
     FR       Complete    245
```

---

More info : What I usually do is `reset_index`

```
df1=df.copy().reset_index()
df[df1.country.ne('US').groupby(df1['id']).transform('all').values]
Out[486]: 
                status  value
id   country                 
3456 CA        Ongoing     20
     UK       Complete    123
     FR       Complete    245

df[df1.status.ne('Ongoing').groupby(df1['id']).transform('all').values]
Out[487]: 
                status  value
id   country                 
1234 US       Complete     54
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks. Would have never figured that out on my own. What is the benefit of resetting the index?

Comment: @ndevito1 shorten the solution :-)